# Why is my web3.eth.getBlock("pending", true) not working as intended?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

So I was playing around with the web3, but having problem to get the transactions from a block (following https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock)

```
var BlockPromise = web3.eth.getBlock('pending', true);
console.log("Block TX: " + BlockPromise.transactions[0]);
```

I would expect to get a transaction. However, I am only getting a [object Object]

What is my mistake?
FYI: I do not have a coding degree.

Comment: `[object Object]` is what JavaScript prints out when trying to convert an object to a string. Try just `console.log(Block.transactions[0]);`. That should display the full object structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
(async function() {
  var BlockPromise = await web3.eth.getBlock('pending', true);
  console.log("Block TX: " + JSON.stringify(BlockPromise.transactions[0], null, 2));
})();
```

`JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` prints the entire object instead of just `[object Object]`